# Maintaining VC++ projects across several Visual Studio Versions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, migration, project-organization

We have a *Windows Desktop only* product suite that consists of several `.exe` applications and (obviously) quite a bunch of shared libraries between these apps. There's about 20 exe apps and maybe also about 20 shared libraries that are each used by several of these apps (some libs are very specific, some are just your good(?) old `FooUtils.dll`) Most code is C++, some C#.

Currently, all these reside in a [single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) Visual Studio 2005 solution and are all built and released together. That works quite fine and each developer always can edit / see / debug any code he needs to. About 15 devs (mixed C++ / C#) on that product suite.

## Now the problem

Due to migration pressure (language features, new 3rd party components) it becomes increasingly urgent to migrate *some* of the apps (read `.exe`projects) to newer visual studio versions. Some to VS 2010 maybe (3rd party dependencies) some to VS2015. And *some* we just have *not* the resources to migrate them from VS2005 yet (third party constraints, as well as time/budget constraints).

This means that *several* of the shared **C++** libraries will have to exist for several visual studio versions. (As opposed to the exe projects - these would just be built/maintained for one chosen VS version.)

## Now the question

Given a set of (internal) shared libraries that need to be created for multiple different Visual-C++-Versions and that should be *easily editable and maintainable* for all devs, **how are we to keep the Utils.vcproj(2005) the Utils.vcxproj(2010) and the Utils.vcxproj(2015) in sync?**

Mostly to avoid manually having to maintain all files contained in the projects, but also regarding project settings / `.[vs]props` settings for these projects.

---

Ideas we had so far:

- Just accept annoying triple maintenance of 3 project files in 3 different solutions (ugh.)
- Use one of the `vc..` project files as the master project and automatically (how??!) generate the other `vc..`files from it.
- Use tools like [CMake](https://cmake.org/), [Premake](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki), ... ?? to generate these shared-shared library projects. (That would mean introducing a foreign configuration tool for our devs)

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid manually updating your project files in separate versions of Visual Studio, you'll have to have a master configuration for the project of one sort or another. The two options you listed are basically your options:

- Use one project version as the 'master'. In this case, the master must be the oldest version (VS2005 in your case?). Visual Studio has a [project upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690665.aspx) feature, to convert older projects to newer versions. When you load up an older project in a newer version, it prompts you to upgrade. This process can be automated with some simple scripting. Using `devenv.exe <project/solution file> /upgrade` you can upgrade a project from the [command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15a82ay.aspx).
- Use CMake/Premake/etc. These add a little bit of overhead, but making supporting new platforms and configurations a lot less painless. If adding new dev tools is cumbersome to your process, and you're only supporting Visual Studio, the first option might be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to share whether you ever have been in a similar situation? Any experience which cross platform tool would be most appropriate in this situation?

Comment: I've worked on projects that use cmake, and it's generally good for cross platform project management (although, obviously just my opinion). It's become more and more widely used.

I've worked on another project that was compiled on around 15 *platforms*, across 5 versions of MSVC, all updated by hand. I would actually just keep stuffing new classes into old files, just to avoid the pain of updating projects. Terrible stuff. For best results and sanity: don't do that.